# How can I change the name of a QButtonGroup in QT designer?

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I know how to add buttons to a buttongroup, but I can't find anywhere to change the buttongroup

Comment: "can't find anywhere to change the buttongroup" - change it to what?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Highlight the buttons, right click and select "Assign to Button Group -> New Button Group". This creates a new `QButtonGroup` in the object inspector pane (usually top right). There, you can change the name of the group by double clicking on the left cell titled "Object".

[image]

Comment: That feeling when you need a detailed screenshot merely to explain a single user experience (UX) operation. Did the interface really need to be *this* non-intuitively obtuse, The Qt Company?